# problems in create advanced search using query

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem in creating advanced search with custom query and using `$wpdb->get_results($query , OBJECT);`

In Normal search in wordpress when we search `xxx yyyy` or search `yyyy xxx` we have same results and it's good.
But when I am forced to use query to create an advanced search then sequence of words in search fields are important and further  `xxx yyyy` or search `yyyy xxx` aren't same result.
I want to say with an example:
I create two input field one for Title and another for Author of my posts(Author is an example only and in this place is a custom fields )
I try to read these fields and search them in wordpress

```
<?php
$t = $_REQUEST['title'];
$a = $_REQUEST['author'];
global $wpdb;
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts, wp_postmeta WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id";

if ($t != '') {
    $t_sql = " AND wp_posts.post_title like '%$t%' ";
}

if ($a != '') {
    $a_sql = " AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'Author' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value like '%$a%' ";
}
$query .= $t_sql;
$query .= $a_sql;
$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($query , OBJECT);
global $post;

if ($pageposts):
foreach ($pageposts as $post):
setup_postdata($post);
//...
endforeach;
endif;
?>
```

In Your idea, What do I must to do?

Comment: Could you please add some additional details in your question? And give the meanings of the functions if you want. Are you did this before? What is the `OBJECT` in your code? Is the `$query` a SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split up your search terms by a `Space` character and then construct your query to look up every possible order of the words. Here is an example for your `Title` field:

```
// Assuming the title is "One Two Three"
$t = $_REQUEST['title'];

// Split the TITLE by space character
$terms = explode(' ', $t); // $terms = ["One", "Two", "Three"]

// Concats each search term with a LIKE operator
$temp = array();
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $temp[] = "title LIKE '%".$term."%'";
    // $temp = ["title LIKE %One%", "title LIKE %Two%", ...
}

// Adds an AND operator for each $temp to the query statement
$query = "SELECT * FROM titleTable WHERE (".implode(' AND ', $temp).")";
// $query = SELECT * FROM titleTable WHERE 
       // (title LIKE '%One%' AND title LIKE '%Two%' AND title LIKE '%Three%')
```

Answer (score 1):

Making custom query which search in the WP DB is not a good way. Use the WP_Query to do this.

Here is a link where someone was experiencing the same problem:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18703/wp-query-with-post-title-like-something

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I've review your code on web developer portals, specially the SQL queries. And I also didn't knew why by searching *xxx yyyy* and *yyyy xxx* aren't same result with your PHP script. But the only tips that I can give to you:

```
$query .= $t_sql;
$query .= $a_sql;
// is to add an sql order by keyword like this
$query .= " ORDER BY wp_posts . post_title ";
```

Give it a try! And don't forget to `addslashes()` when you used `$_GET`, `$_POST` or `$_COOKIE` variable if the PHP of your server doesn't runs `addslashes()` on those variables. You can check this by using the function `get_magic_quotes_gpc()`.