# how can i search having search key of multiple values from the column of a table containing multiple values

Tags: mysql

I want  to create a Mysql search that can take multiple values from dropdown(multiple) and search and match them in one column which is containing multiple values.

sample :-

```
column containing multiple values (in a row)= abc pqr xyz
```

and multiple dropdown menu containing

```
abc
xyz
pqr
def
```

user can select these values in any order

so my problem is how can i create a search so that my search key should match with any of the values in the column.

Comment: Please tell us what did you try so far to achieve this. At least research but preferably some code.

Comment: You should split your drop down's values by `space` and then generate a SQL query like this: `SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE 
(columnName LIKE '%abc%' AND columnName LIKE '%pqr%' AND columnName LIKE '%xyz%')`. I have answered something similar for PHP [`here`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15806021/1693859).

Answer (score 0):

First of all there are no "drop downs" in mysql.

MySql is a database, and a drop down is a user interface item.

In order to search a database for multiple items you can do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myColumn = 'value1' OR myColumn = 'value2'
```

or you can do it this way, but it is typically slower:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myColumn IN ('value1','value2','value3')
```

As far as creating the drop down, well that is a topic for another question.  Are you doing so on a webpage or application?  What language?  Your question is very open ended.